# My Gun move according to mouse movement but also rotate on its axis when firing bullet Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

When i Press Left Click to shoot bullets and mean while(When left mouse button is still clicked) i move the gun right and left my gun keep on shooting bullets but also start rotating about its origin?
But if i Dont Click the left mouse button and move gun,it dont rotate about its axis...

```js
var clickPos    : Vector2;
var offsetPos   : Vector2;
var divider     = 80;

function Start()
{
    clickPos = Vector2(0,0);
    offsetPos = Vector2(0,0);
}

function Update () {

    offsetPos = Vector2(0,0);

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(leftClick()))
    {
        clickPos = mouseXY();
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(leftClick()))
    {
        offsetPos = clickPos - mouseXY();
    }


    transform.Rotate(Vector3(-(offsetPos.y/divider),offsetPos.x/divider,0.0), Space.World);
}

// Prints the current mouse position
function OnGUI ()
{
    /*GUI.Label(Rect(10,350,200,100), "mouse X = " + Input.mousePosition.x);
    GUI.Label(Rect(10,370,200,100), "mouse Y = " + Input.mousePosition.y);

    GUI.Label(Rect(120,350,200,100), "click X = " + clickPos.x);
    GUI.Label(Rect(120,370,200,100), "click Y = " + clickPos.y);

    GUI.Label(Rect(210,350,200,100), "offset X = " + offsetPos.x);
    GUI.Label(Rect(210,370,200,100), "offset Y = " + offsetPos.y);*/
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////

// Return true when left mouse is clicked or hold
function leftClick()
{
    return KeyCode.Mouse0;
}

//Immediate location of the mouse
function mouseXY()
{
    return Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
}

//Immediate location of the mouse's X coordinate
function mouseX()
{
    return Input.mousePosition.x;
}

//Immediate location of the mouse's Y coordinate
function mouseY()
{
    return Input.mousePosition.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got The Answer
The Answer Is 
TO Comment the Offset Values,Every Where Being Used In the Code.
Keep the Code Simple And comment or eliminate the Line Of Rotation from the Code so that no act of rotation can perform on the Gun,Only position changes on movement.